# Issue with JSON parse

Tags: c#, json

I'm storing `JSON` data into class. However, I'm having difficult time solving the second `JSON` line below, `BadGuy`. I cannot store it's data correctly.

```
{
     \"First\":{\"FirstBool\":1, \"aString\":\"hello\"},
     \"BadGuy\":\"BadGuy says hello\" //<--- this one, how do I tackle this in code below?
}
```

---

```
public class First
{
    [JsonProperty("FirstBool")]
    public int FirstBool { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("aString")]
    public string aString { get; set; }
}     

public class BadGuy //my poorly attempt
{
    [JsonProperty("BadGuy")]
    public string BadGuy { get; set; }
}


public class ClsResult
{
    [JsonProperty("First")]
    public First First { get; set; }    

   [JsonProperty("BadGuy")] // another poorly attempt
    public BadGuy BadGuy { get; set; }
}
```

How I deserialize my `JSON`:

```
var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClsResult>(myJSON);
```

Comment: There is no `BadGuy` type, change `BadGuy` property to type `string`.

Comment: @Sinatr  you mean like `[JsonProperty("string")]` in `BadGuy` class?

Comment: Nope, see @AndySkirrow answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this? `BadGuy` is a string so you should define it as such.

```
public class First
{
    [JsonProperty("FirstBool")]
    public int FirstBool { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("aString")]
    public string aString { get; set; }
}      

public class ClsResult
{
    [JsonProperty("First")]
    public First First { get; set; }    

    [JsonProperty("BadGuy")] 
    public string BadGuy { get; set; }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
         string json = GetJson();
         ClsResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClsResult>(myJSON);
         Console.WriteLine("Bad Guy == " + result.BadGuy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, do I access the `BadGuy` string via `var test = new ClsResult();` --> `test.BadGuy` then? EDIT: Also, so `BadGuy`-class is no longer useful, meaning I should delete that class code?

Comment: Yes you can delete the "BadGuy" class. See updated example. If it doesn't work then please say what error you are getting.